# Managing Fragments inside tabs

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, android-activity, android-actionbar

I'm creating a simple Activity, which contains two tabs. I'm following the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Tabs), so I'm using `Fragment`. 
In my Activity there are only two tabs. The first one is a Map (`MapFragment`), while the second is a simple List (`ListFragment`)

All works good, my only problem is that I can't manage correctly the map.

In the `onTabSelected` callback I have use the following code:

```
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    if (mFragment == null) {
        mFragment = Fragment.instantiate(mActivity, mClass.getName(), mArgs);
        ft.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment, mTag);
    } else {
        ft.attach(mFragment);

        if(mTag.compareToIgnoreCase("map")==0)
            setUpMapIfNeeded((MapFragment)mFragment);

    }
}
```

where map is the tag of my first Activity and the mthod `setUpMapIfNeeded` is:

```
private static void setUpMapIfNeeded(MapFragment mMapFragment) {
    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
    if (mMap == null) {
        mMap = mMapFragment.getMap();
        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
        if (mMap != null) {
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
        }
    }
}
```

So the marker is added in the map only if I select the tab.

**The questione is: How can I modify my code for performing the addMarker action also when the activity is started (without pressing explicitly the first tab)?**

Answer (score 0):

I would think that you could:

1. Refactor the content of onTabSelected to call a addMapFragment(FragmentTransaction ft), just put the whole code inside the addMapFragment method and return the FragmentTransaction. onTabSelected then becomes:

   ```
   public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
       // if map tab
       ft = addMapFragment(ft);
   }
   ```
2. This will make it easy to handle the map and markers in onCreate:

   ```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       ...
       if (savedInstanceState != null) {
           // not first startup - map should already be created with markers
       } else {
           FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentMangager.beginTransaction();
           ft = addMapFragment(ft);
           ft.commit();
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved adding this code:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();

    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    Fragment f = fm.findFragmentByTag("map");
    if(f!= null && f.isAdded())
        setUpMapIfNeeded((MapFragment)f);
}
```

Comment: is a solution but then you add the markers each and every time onResume is called and the map is added. If you have many markers at some point, this will really slow down your app.